# How to copy urls that links to my website?

Tags: url, hyperlink, seo, refer

In google when I search something I can copy that link like:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=20&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CG0QFjAJOApqFQoTCLiug_rflsgCFUm-FAod1HgEdw&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftorrent.ir%2F&usg=AFQjCNGgyh3cWO6toVX5_l1WOsjBiLx-Ig&sig2=fENHbcmKvitVYyKK3XJI2g&bvm=bv.103388427,d.d24

I need this for SEO of my website...
but I can't copy links from other sites like ask or bing?
How can i copy urls that refers to my site from another site?

Comment: Do you mean visitors that arrive at your site from another source? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer Or do you mean you want to know which search engines link to your site?

Comment: In google search I can copy referd url of my website but in bing i can't get the refered url like google and get it like mysite.com , I need it for ads like pop up

Answer (score 0):

In SEO term it is called as "Back links". You can easily check backlinks of your website from the following tools:

```
http://www.backlinkwatch.com/

https://ahrefs.com/

http://smallseotools.com/backlink-checker/
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are talking about getting access to the HTTP referrer, according to Bing, you can only get access to the domain name, and no longer the search query that the visitor used with Bing, in order to protect the user's privacy.

https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2015/06/15/bing-moving-to-encrypt-search-traffic-by-default/

> With the move to encrypted search by default we will continue to pass
>   along a referrer string so that marketers and webmasters will be able
>   to identify traffic as coming from Bing. However, to further protect
>   our users’ privacy, we will not include the used query terms.

Comment: Downvoting w/o explanation? Not useful.